# app.get getting called twice for both new and show in express:nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, npm, ejs, node-modules

```
app.get("/foodcamp/new", (req, res) => {
    console.log(1);
    res.render("./new.ejs");
    console.log(2);
});


app.get("/foodcamp/:foodID", (req, res) =>{
  console.log(3);
  var fetchedFoodID = req.params.foodID;
  Food.find({_id: fetchedFoodID}).then((fetchedFood)=>{
        res.render("./show.ejs",{foundFood:fetchedFood[0]})
  }, (error)=>{
    console.log("error2")
  })
});
```

When I go to the URL "http://localhost:8080/foodcamp/new", I am getting the following O/P at console:

```
1
2
3
error2
```

Comment: I figured out that the src of script tag in footer.ejs (inside partials) was "app.js", while it was supposed to be "/app.js" . But I did not understand why that caused the second get route to be called. After making the aforementioned changes the routes are behaving as intended.

Comment: The reason the /foodcamp/:foodID route is being called is because /foodcamp/new also matches the route signature. If foodID is supposed to be a number, then you can configure the route to only look at numeric ids: `/foodcamp/:foodID(\d+)`

Comment: The id  is mongodb "_ids". They are not specifically numeric. It had something to do with header.ejs (partial file). It was <script type="text/javascript" src="**demo.js**">
While  it should have been <script type="text/javascript" src="**/demo.js**">

Comment: Interesting, so :foodID was actually demo.js. In the future, to avoid these kinds of issues you can set a base href (eg: <base href="/">) on your documents (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).